# Problem connecting external monitors/ display after Ubuntu software upgrade on 20.04 | 18-Jan-2022

Tags: 20.04, display, intel, thinkpad

I've gone through all existing threads on AskUbuntu and none solves the problem I'm having.

After running software update on Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday (18-01-2022), this morning both my monitors do not display anything. I have Lenovo Thinkpad L390 and use Thinkpad hub / docking station. Mouse, headphones and keyboard connected through this hub work fine though. In order to eliminate problem with the hub, I left one display connected through the hub, and the second directly to the laptop. Both displays still do not display anything.

Specs:

```
user@evelyn:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: i915 tty: N/A 
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.3.4 - kisak-mesa PPA
```

The laptop has one graphic card:

```
user@evelyn:~$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
    Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Kernel version:

```
5.13.0-27-generic
```

In Software&Updates > Additional Drivers the section is empty, doesn't show any drivers.

In Settings > Screen Display shows only the built in laptop display, the other two do not appear.